# React start landing url

Tags: reactjs

I am new here and I have a question about React JS. I used the create-react-app tool to initialize my application. I wanted to ask how can I change the initial landing page when I start the application.

For example when i am executing 'npm start' it will go to open a new tab in the browser with url 'localhost:3000'. Now I want when I execute this command to open at localhost:3000/api.

Thank you for your time

Nick

Answer (score 8):

You can edit the `homepage` in `package.json`

```
"homepage": "https://your website url/route of what you want start with",
```

for example:

```
"homepage": "https://icecreamzhao.github.io/api",
```

When you start the react application, you'll find that the app runs by opening the url `http://localhost:3000/api` as you expect.

Refer [React docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths) for more info

Comment: I prefer this solution to react-router for answering the original question because it *only* affects the behavior of `npm start` in the dev environment and doesn't require adding a package. Also noting that `"homepage": "/api"` should work and gives more flexibility for port assignment, e.g. serving multiple web apps in dev environment.

Comment: I found that this method may also impact the JavaScript + CSS output paths that are rendered into the index.html file, when using the files unedited from the React template.

Comment: I was hoping ```"homepage": "https://blah.localhost.mycompany.com/api"``` would actually open  ```https://blah.localhost.mycompany.com/api``` - as I'm using a reverse proxy locally.

Answer (score 6):

You should be using [react router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router), then you'll be able to redirect the root path to where you want:

```
<Redirect from='/' to='/api' />
```

Or, if you want the sub-path without redirection, you can use basename like:

```
<Router basename={'/api'}>
  <Route path="/" component={Api} />
</Router
```

Now, when you start the project, it will serve from `your_domain:port/api`

---

If you don't use react router, then you may set homepage in package.json like:

```
"homepage": "/api"
```

Comment: I know this trick but the problem is that I want to open there without using the / path. I want my application to start work with context path the '/api' and not the '/'

Comment: No Prob. I am just asking if there is any way when I am executing the npm start to open immediate the 'localhost:3000/api' without Router component or Redirect. If there is any configuration/property

Comment: Updated for that.

Comment: I tried this one and it still opens in localhost:3000 without the /api

Comment: I think this will only be for build ie. for production.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React routing you can add using the prop basename

```
<Router basename={'api'}>
```

Or if you want to change the default loading port you'll need to modify the core file which is not recommended

node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/statr.js

```
const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
```

Thanks

Comment: I am using Router with basename the value {'api'} but when I want to go at localhost:3000/api immediate when I start the application and not go to localhost:3000 and I have to write the 'api'. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

setting
"Homepage" : "/home"

in package.json worked for me.
now it opens to /home when i 'npm start'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I',m assuming you are using React Router version 6.

From app level you could use the `basename` property in `BrowserRouter` and configure all sub routes from there. i.e.: `<BrowserRouter basename="/api">` and also add the property in package.json to `"http://localhost:3000/api"`to make react starts from that route in localhost.

In case you have an application configured at root path `/` and also the api under `/api` you could use just the property `homepage` in `package.json`. This is also valid for `React router v5`