# how to configure the landing page in React web application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I created a **ReactJS** project with the `create-react-app` package and that worked well, also I'm starting the application using `npm start` command.

So the application is landing on `http://localhost:3000` by default, but I wanted to configure my landing URL to something like this `http://localhost:3000/google` where `/google` will be useful to configure the `apache web server` to detect my application.

**NOTE:** There is a way to redirect using `react-router-dom` to `<Redirect from="/" to="/google" />` option and this will work once the application is loaded. But I am expecting my application should be accessible only with this URL `http://localhost:3000/google`. That means all my `webpack, node_modules, public` URL should go via `/google` only.

How to configure the base URL of web application ?

Comment: did you refer routing and routing redirect

Comment: when I am executing the `npm start` to open immediate the `localhost:3000/google` without Router component or Redirect

Comment: do you need subfolder routing,

Comment: No. I have updated my question

Comment: hope you are looking  build app into sub folder. https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1
take a look at the article

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the answer to your question here: [React Start Landing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591686/react-start-landing-url)

The first one by @Bhojendra Rauniyar

Hope it helps!

Comment: when I am executing the `npm start` the application itself should start with `localhost:3000/google` without Router component or Redirect. That means all my `webpack, node_modules, public` URL should go via /google only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router you can use the basename prop to set the sub directory

```
<BrowserRouter basename='/google'>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

OR you can redirect / to /content in your Switch block

```
<Switch>
   <Redirect exact from="/" to="/google" />
   <Route exact path="/google" component={ContentComponent} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: when I am executing the `npm start` the application itself should start with `localhost:3000/google` without Router component or Redirect.

Comment: Currently other than this, there is no other way. However, they are trying to add this feature of configuring the URL. You can check it here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/7259